# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found: _dlopen, matlab_wrapper

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to use matlab_wrapper to run a matlab program with python. I'm just starting and I can't even open the MatlabSession. I use visual studio to compile my code.

I've already read a bit about the subject but none of what I found helped me
(the matlabroot is correct, I got it from asking matlab directly just to be sure).

my input:

```
import matlab_wrapper

matlab = matlab_wrapper.MatlabSession(options='-nosplash',matlab_root='C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a')
```

output:

```
File "c:/Mandats/XV/UQ_LAB/python/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    matlab = matlab_wrapper.MatlabSession(options='-nosplash',matlab_root='C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a')
  File "C:\Mandats\XV\UQ_LAB\python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matlab_wrapper\matlab_session.py", line 113, in __init__
    engine, libeng, libmx, version = load_engine_and_libs(matlab_root, options)
  File "C:\Mandats\XV\UQ_LAB\python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matlab_wrapper\matlab_session.py", line 317, in load_engine_and_libs
    libeng = Library('libeng')
  File "C:\Mandats\XV\UQ_LAB\python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matlab_wrapper\matlab_session.py", line 790, in __init__
    self._lib = ctypes.CDLL(name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Mandats\XV\UQ_LAB\python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: error in module

Comment: You are running 32-bit Python and it looks very much as if you are trying to load a 64-bit version of matlab. That is precisely the error you get if you try to load a DLL of the wrong bitness.